# How to make Popup via storyboard(xib?) and programmatically Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, popup, uialertcontroller

For some reason i want to know how exactly i can implement **Popup** in Xamarin.iOS via **storyboard** and **programmatically**.

---

At current moment, i'm doing pretty simple workaround:

Inside designer, i'm dropping additional view(as popup) and configure like that
`MyPopupView.Hidden = true;`

After some steps(nvm), i'm showing this popup via

`MyPopupView.Hidden = false;`

And the **result** is :
[image]

Yeah, that is bad and very poor approach, because what if need these 5 guys  or more ?
 I will not be able to design my ***ViewController***, because it will be stuffed with these views.
Also, for some reason i want to show **arrow**(see img below) and **shadow**(outside of popup) for better usability.

---

That what is exactly i want to do :
[image]

or this one(but inside, i want to put for e.g. my xib or VC,where i can drop some other views, like .gif animation):
[image]

or this one:
[image]

and finally, what i want(this one is amazing) :
[image]

---

Main idea to use storyboard(to make life easy with working on constraints and autolayout),but maybe it can be done programmatically the same.

I think that is possible to do that with **UIAlertController** , just needs to insert our **View**  , but dunno is that right approach.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two images you posted can be accomplished using storyboards.

Essentially what you to do is create a separate scene/view controller in your storyboard and set it's presentation property to *"over current context"*. 
[image]
[image]

Alternatively you can set the segue to "Show modally" and the presentation property of the segue to "over current context" in Xcode

[image]

(for some reason the "Over current context" option doesn't come up in Xamarin Studio (at least not in Xamarin Studio 6) and when you open it back up in XS it will display a "Error while creating this entry" message by the presentation property but it should still work).

The next step is to set the root view to be transparent (background color = *clear color*) and then have a child view with your content.

[image]

If you want the semi-transparent overlay affect then what you can do is have two *"sibling"* child views one with your content (same as before) and a second view which is constrained to the edges of the root view and has it's alpha property set to something less then 1.

[image]

[image]

And here's the result...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. i have tried to something like this. I have made another VC with 320height - 320width size and after this,i was doing   like that :    YourController yourController = new YourController();

    yourController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
    this.PresentViewController(yourController, true, null);  and no luck. It's streched to fully screen.  

About your "presentation property",hmm..didn't hear this,but seems that https://youtu.be/CXvOS6hYADc?t=379 this feature also isn't support by XS.

Comment: The presentation property on the view controller does appear in XS, the one on the segue doesn't appear in XS but seems to work if you set it using xcode (you can right click on your storyboard and select open with xcode).

Comment: As for the size, I would have it set to *freeform* and then set the background color of the root view to *clear color* (transparent) and then have a child view that is the container for all the content you want to be displayed in the popup (you can constrain that child view to the center of controller)

Comment: seems that you're right. I have made it in XCode, and it shows on XS https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3uVB.png , but i cant modify them :|,only setup and that it :(. Is this a good approach,to have billion views inside Viewcontrollers? I have made freeform and also changed background of my little VC. OK, but without containerview it can be done?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by modify them? It's a separate view controller and you can set whatever properties (either in your `PrepareForSegue` method or after instantiating your VC from your storyboard) you want on it and control it within that VC.

Comment: seems missunderstanding from me. Can you provide example,please?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what part your having trouble with? I'll try and add an example and more detailed instructions later today.

Comment: this part with "your storyboard and set it's presentation property on the segue itself in Xcode " . OKay,thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'll have a chance be able to update my answer further today (will try tomorrow).

Comment: I've added step by step screen shots which I hope will be helpful.

Comment: thanks for great screenshots. I have no idea, but it not works in XS(i'm doing step by steP), also pretty the same job in Xcode(native style), works as excepted... What the hell:( ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140111/discussion-between-jack-and-xtl).